# Issue going javascript to coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm newbie with coffescript and I'm trying use coffee instead javascript for this example:

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs

```
var request = require('request'),
jsdom = require('jsdom');

request({ uri:'http://www.google.com' }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
  console.log('Error when contacting google.com')
}

  jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: [
    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
            ]
    }, function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.jQuery;

   // jQuery is now loaded on the jsdom window created from 'agent.body'
    console.log($('body').html());
   });
});
```

my coffee code is this:

```
request = require 'request'
sys     = require 'sys'
jsdom   = require 'jsdom'

request uri: 'http://www.google.com' , (error,response,body) ->
  console.log "hay un error al conectar" if error && response.statusCode !=200
  #sys.puts(body)

  jsdom.env html : body , scripts : ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'], (err, window) ->
      $ = window.JQuery
      console.log( $('body').html())
```

when compile and run it..this does nothing...I've inspected the compile code and for me it's ok and I've used the converter from http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/ and the generated code is almost exactly to my js code...

In this code I have omitted several brackets but I've tried with these too and didn't work neither I don't know where is the mistake

thanks for read and help :D

Comment: window.JQuery? upper-case J?

Comment: Have you tried running the original javascript to confirm it works in your environment?  It could be a configuration problem with Node, not a problem writing the correct CoffeeScript.  Otherwise, I agree with @tokland - could be the capital J

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code thru http://js2coffee.org/ and got this. There are some small differences but the capital J in JQuery is the most likely culprit.

```
request = require("request")
jsdom = require("jsdom")
request
  uri: "http://www.google.com"
, (error, response, body) ->
  console.log "Error when contacting google.com"  if error and response.statusCode isnt 200
  jsdom.env
    html: body
    scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"]
  , (err, window) ->
    $ = window.jQuery

    # jQuery is now loaded on the jsdom window created from 'agent.body'
    console.log $("body").html()
```

Comment: I just wrote this out myself, and I am amazed at how well js2coffee has converted it, it was almost identical. +1 for js2coffee